# iOS: Create image from non-premultiplied [UInt8]

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have a `[UInt8]` that contains color data in RGBA format. I need to create an image from this data in the most efficient way. Currently, this is what I have:

```
extension CGImage {
  static func fromData(content: [UInt8], width: Int, height: Int) -> CGImage? {
    guard content.count == width * height * 4,
          let space = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) else {
      return nil
    }
    var content = content
    let context = CGContext(
      data: &content,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      bitsPerComponent: 8,
      bytesPerRow: width * 4,
      space: space,
      bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    )

    let image = context?.makeImage()
    return image
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that I must use `CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast` (I read somewhere else that iOS only supports premultiplied data) which requires me to do the alpha-multiplication first. I'm using metal to do that, but on big images, it takes around 8ms to do that. Added with other processing time, I ended up with a laggy drawing experience.

Do we have any other way of creating an image from non-premultiplied `[UInt8]`? It can be `CGImage`, `CIImage`, or `UIImage`.

Comment: Have you tried `CGImageAlphaInfo.last`? From the docs: "The alpha component is stored in the least significant bits of each pixel. For example, non-premultiplied RGBA."

Comment: I did, but it get this 
`unsupported parameter combination:
 RGB | 8 bits/component, integer | 1024 bytes/row.
 kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGImageByteOrderDefault | 
kCGImagePixelFormatPacked`

Comment: I also tried `CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little`, but got pretty much the same thing

Comment: It seems you are right and `CGContext` doesn't support non-premultiplied alpha. I think it would be best if your drawing engine could already output premultiplied pixel data. This should be more efficient for alpha blending also.

Comment: that's a lot of work. And also not good for other calculations as they all work with non-premultiplied data like blending mode. but yea, if no one else has a solution then I guess I have to do that